# Unresponsive django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker (not showing calendar)

Tags: django, widget, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

As a beginner I often struggle with understanding the connections between Python-Django, html, javascript and css.

The problem at hand is this: I'm trying to implement DateTimePicker widget from [django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker-2](https://github.com/tutorcruncher/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker).

Since this library does not include js/css assets, I started by implementing datetimepicker without backend involvement just to see if I loaded all static files etc. correctly. Thus, I added [this example](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to html template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything worked as intended, so I tried to implement datetimepicker as a widget from django forms:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    pick_a_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=DateTimePicker(options={
            "format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
            "pickTime": False}
        ))
```

I also wanted to benefit from form wizard (namely SessionWizardView from formtools.wizard), so I output the above mentioned form into html like this:

```
  <form action="" method="post" role="form">{% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
      {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
      {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
          {{ form }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      {{ wizard.form }}
    {% endif %}
  </table>
```

However, the widget is not responsive (the calendar window isn't showing, the glyphicon-calendar icon doesn't do anything). When I leave the test datetime picker (the recently-working one), both break.

Developer's console prints the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: option pickTime is not recognized!
    at Boolean.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:1440)
    at Function.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.picker.options (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:1436)
    at dateTimePicker (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:2276)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:2309)
    at Function.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.$.fn.datetimepicker (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:2304)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):154)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
```

I'm baffled, I don't even know where to look. Do you know any articles or documentation that would explain this to me? Please advise.

I went through some githubs projects and they don't seem to have anything more than I have (especially I was worried that it was something with templatetags, but most have just {% load bootstrap3 %}, some have {% load static %}, which I also have). I've also tried this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760920/samuelcolvins-django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker-not-showing-calendar-when-clicke).

Comment: How did you install the package? Is there any output in the browser's console?

Comment: pip install git+https://github.com/tutorcruncher/django-bootstrap3-
datetimepicker (this fork supports Django 1.11). Browser console says 'Uncaught TypeError: option pickTime is not recognized!' I'll add the whole thing to the post.

Comment: Can you remove the package you installed and then re-install it using `pip install django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker-2`?

Comment: Just did. Still nothing :(

Comment: Can you try changing the Django form's format to `dd/MM/YYYY`? Also, remove `pickTime` from the form.

Comment: Yep. That was it. Thanks man :) Do you perhaps know is it possible to disable time? Now the form outputs date ending with '00:00:00+00:00'. I don't see such option on http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: please accept my answer if you're satisfied with it. I'm sure it's possible to disable time, but give me just a moment to figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Django form's format to `dd/MM/YYYY`. Additionally, remove `pickTime` from the form. I believe those were changed in an earlier release; perhaps the example you used was outdated.

Comment: @Pawel changing the format back to `yyyy-mm-dd` may actually disable `hasTime`. Try that.

Comment: Unfortunately both order of letters and capital letters have to stay. Plus, from time to time I've been getting random validation errors, so temporarily I've swich to "format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm". I'd be glad for a solution to this problem, though.

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out. Apparently, the hours/minutes showing up is determined by the format.